# Búsqueda en mapa con autocompletado no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

Estoy implementando el autocompletado de la API de Google Maps, para que busque dentro de un polígono de coordenadas la dirección y se valide que esté dentro del mismo.

El problema es que funciona, hasta que ingreso la dirección (como ejemplo) de "San Juan 2638", y **si la selecciono dando clic con el mouse en las sugerencias**, el resultado es una búsqueda en el mapa en los Estados Unidos, cuando debería ser en Rosario, Argentina.

Espero puedan ayudarme

Les dejo el código completo de lo que estoy haciendo

**JS:**

```
    /*=============================================
    AUTOCOMPLETADO GOOGLE + MAPA
    =============================================*/

    function initAutocomplete() {

        var pac_input = document.getElementById('registroDireccion');

        var autocomplete_options = {
                         types: ['address'],
                         componentRestrictions: {country: "ar"}
        };

        /*=============================================
        SELECCION DE PRIMER SUGERENCIA AL DAR "ENTER"
        =============================================*/

        (function pacSelectFirst(input) {
            // store the original event binding function
            var _addEventListener = (input.addEventListener) ? input.addEventListener : input.attachEvent;

            function addEventListenerWrapper(type, listener) {
                // Simulate a 'down arrow' keypress on hitting 'return' when no pac suggestion is selected,
                // and then trigger the original listener.
                if (type == "keydown") {
                    var orig_listener = listener;
                    listener = function(event) {
                        var suggestion_selected = $(".pac-item-selected").length > 0;
                        if (event.which == 13 && !suggestion_selected) {
                            var simulated_downarrow = $.Event("keydown", {
                                keyCode: 40,
                                which: 40
                            });
                            orig_listener.apply(input, [simulated_downarrow]);
                        }

                        orig_listener.apply(input, [event]);
                    };
                }

                _addEventListener.apply(input, [type, listener]);
            }

            input.addEventListener = addEventListenerWrapper;
            input.attachEvent = addEventListenerWrapper;

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocomplete_options);

        })(pac_input);

            /*=============================================
            VALIDAR DIRECCIÓN DENTRO DEL POLÍGONO DE COORDENADAS
            =============================================*/

            // Creamos la instacia bounds
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            // Extraemos las coordenadas
            var coords = [

                    {"lat": -32.9524231, "lng": -60.6682936},{"lat": -32.9719713, "lng": -60.67327},{"lat": -32.9741199, "lng": -60.6609489},{"lat": -32.9672002, "lng": -60.6591224},{"lat": -32.9717621, "lng": -60.6342073},{"lat": -32.9694741, "lng": -60.6335479},{"lat": -32.9715067, "lng": -60.6218164},{"lat": -32.9680472, "lng": -60.6205835},{"lat": -32.9630917, "lng": -60.6216094},{"lat": -32.958511, "lng": -60.6209314},{"lat": -32.9521298, "lng": -60.624212},{"lat": -32.9520442, "lng": -60.6251776},{"lat": -32.9503966, "lng": -60.6262076},{"lat": -32.9501265, "lng": -60.6256068},{"lat": -32.9462216, "lng": -60.6283345},{"lat": -32.9380717, "lng": -60.636903},{"lat": -32.9317529, "lng": -60.6468345},{"lat": -32.9265583, "lng": -60.6577651},{"lat": -32.9176559, "lng": -60.6700872},{"lat": -32.9182323, "lng": -60.6901178},{"lat": -32.9197859, "lng": -60.6891415},{"lat": -32.9284696, "lng": -60.6885702},{"lat": -32.9282011, "lng": -60.6780258},{"lat": -32.9294789, "lng": -60.6778898},{"lat": -32.9294001, "lng": -60.6743024},{"lat": -32.9333037, "lng": -60.6713756},{"lat": -32.9334751, "lng": -60.6734615},{"lat": -32.9351777, "lng": -60.6738827},{"lat": -32.9344493, "lng": -60.677983},{"lat": -32.9377555, "lng": -60.6788352},{"lat": -32.9360567, "lng": -60.6882969},{"lat": -32.9374164, "lng": -60.6886667},{"lat": -32.9364591, "lng": -60.6936267},{"lat": -32.9405789, "lng": -60.6936545},{"lat": -32.9481519, "lng": -60.6934212}

                ] 

            // Agregamos la coordenada al bounds
            .map(function(coord) {

                bounds.extend(coord);
                return coord;

            });

            // Creamos el poligono
            var area = new google.maps.Polygon({

                paths: coords,
                strokeColor: '#F99830',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#F99830',
                fillOpacity: 0.30,
                draggable: false

            });

            // Creamos el mapa
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

                zoom: 12.6,
                center: bounds.getCenter(), // Centramos el mapa al area
                mapTypeId: 'terrain',
                disableDefaultUI: true

            });

            // Agregamos el area al mapa
            area.setMap(map);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                $('#registroDireccion').on('change', function() {
                    var place = $(this).val().trim();
                    if (!place) {
                        return;
                    }
                    geocoder.geocode({
                            address: place
                        },
                        function(results, status) {

                            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                var result = results[0];
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: result.geometry.location,
                                    map: map,
                                    label: place
                                });

                                if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(result.geometry.location, area)) {

                            $("#registroDireccion").parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>¡GENIAL!</strong> Nuestro sistema de envíos llega a tu domicilio.</div>');

                            } else {

                                $("#registroDireccion").parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>¡QUÉ MAL!</strong> Nuestro sistema de envíos NO llega a tu domicilio.</div>');

                                    document.getElementById("registroDireccion").value = "";

                                }

                            }

                        });

                })

            });

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">


                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroDireccion" name="registroDireccion" placeholder="Dirección de envío" required>

                    </div>

</div>



<div>

        <button type="button" id="mostrarMapa" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-left">Mostrar zona de envío</button>

</div>

                <div class="col-sm-12" id="map"></div>
```

**SCRIPT API GOOGLE:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?library=geometry&key=AIzaSyBDJVJOqxxr1PfcuzMZWYOut0lkGDW1YsU&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Debes pedir las bibliotecas en el mismo parámetro, separadas por comas: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyBDJVJOqxxr1PfcuzMZWYOut0lkGDW1YsU&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>` (no me consta que sea ese el problema. Cuando escribes en el autocompletador, te sugiere direcciones abajo? Debieran desplegarse unas 5

Comment: @amenadiel ahora mismo pruebo eso. Respecto a tu pregunta, sí, me despliega 5 sugerencias y todas son de Argentina, tal como le estoy indicando en mis restricciones de búsqueda con la variable autocomplete_options

Comment: @amenadiel recien he probado con ese cambio de script, pero el problema sigue. Me resulta muy extraño que haga búsquedas por Estados Unidos con esa dirección que doy como ejemplo al hacer con clic del mouse. Si lo hago con ENTER, o escribiendo de forma completa la dirección "San Juan 2638, Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina" funciona correctamente. El problema es el clic del mouse en la sugerencia del autocompletado